# Powershell - Change SQL Server Service Password and Start Service

Tags: powershell, service

The SQL Server service is currently not running.

[image]

I am trying to change the password for my local SQL instance then start the instance using PowerShell.

[image]

I've tried using a remote session as suggested from this site (http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/managing-sql-server-services-with-powershell.html)
**PS - When I run PowerShell ISE 5, I am running it as an admin.**

```
#Create a new remote PowerShell   session and pass in the scrip block to be executed
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName Laptop123   -Credential Domain01\User01   
$UserName = "Domain01\User01" # specify user Name here
$Password = "Password1" # specify Password here 

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList $UserName, $Password   -Scriptblock { 
       param($UserName,   $Password)
    # Start SQL   Server Database engine service (default instance)
       $Svc   = Get-WmiObject   win32_service -filter   "name='MSSQL$SQL2008R2_32BIT'"
       $Svc.Change($Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, $UserName, $Password)
       Stop-Service   -Name 'MSSQL$SQL2008R2_32BIT'   -Force
    Start-Service   'MSSQL$SQL2008R2_32BIT'

    # Start SQL   Server SQL Server Agent service (default instance)
       $Svc   = Get-WmiObject   win32_service -filter   "name='SQLAgent$SQL2008R2_32BIT'"
       $Svc.Change($Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, $Null, $UserName, $Password)
       Stop-Service   -Name 'SQLAgent$SQL2008R2_32BIT'   -Force
    Start-Service   'SQLAgent$SQL2008R2_32BIT'
}
```

However, I end up getting the following errors:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController] does not contain a method named 'Change'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : Laptop123

Service 'SQL Server (SQL2008R2_32BIT) (MSSQL$SQL2008R2_32BIT)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service MSSQL$SQL2008R2_32BIT on computer '.'.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Laptop123
```

Any suggestions on how to change the service password and then start it?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are calling the wrong name of the service in your script try changing the name filter to 'SQL Server (SQL2008R2_32BIT)'

Let me know if that works, if not list any output you may receive from trying that.

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
    + PSComputerName        : Laptop123

Comment: 'Service 'SQL Server (SQL2008R2_32BIT) (MSSQL$SQL2008R2_32BIT)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service MSSQL$SQL2008R2_32BIT on computer '.'.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : Laptop123'

Comment: Just found this, might be of use to you. Hopefully that will be exactly what you need.

http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/changing-service-credentials-using-powershell

Comment: Make sure that the service is not in disabled mode. set the service to automatic or manual mode and then try starting the service